# Posting a message in a remote Queue

Tags: jms, message-queue

I was trying to publish a message to a remote-queue.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Exception in lookup.: `SCF' could not be found. [Root exception is weblogic.corba.cos.naming.NamingContextAnyPackage.NotFound: IDL:weblogic/corba/cos/naming/NamingContextAny/NotFound:1.0]
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.wrapNamingException(Utils.java:65)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:230)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:168)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.producer.group.BridgedProducer.init(BridgedProducer.java:27)
    at com.producer.group.BridgedProducer.main(BridgedProducer.java:61)
Caused by: weblogic.corba.cos.naming.NamingContextAnyPackage.NotFound: IDL:weblogic/corba/cos/naming/NamingContextAny/NotFound:1.0
    at weblogic.corba.cos.naming.NamingContextAnyPackage.NotFoundHelper.read(NotFoundHelper.java:72)
    at weblogic.corba.cos.naming._NamingContextAnyStub.resolve_any(_NamingContextAnyStub.java:87)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:208)
    ... 4 more
```

Included wlclient.jar and jms.jar in the class-path. What must be going wrong in this?

Comment: Can you update post relevant code.

Comment: Got the where the problem is. When restarted it worked fine. Thankq for the response @Nayan Wadekar

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming 'SCF' is your connection factory.
There is nothing wrong with your client, but the 'SCF' Factory could not be found on the server.
Weblogic has complicated and confusing targeting.

In the Weblogic console go to **Services**->**Messaging**->**JMS Modules**.
Click on the JMS Module you created. If you don't have one create one.

Make sure there is a 'Connection Factory' name 'SCF' and it has a value under 'Targets' (mine is myserver)
You need to do the same for the 'Queue' if you have a queue.
If anything under the 'Targets' sections is empty it won't lookup on your client.